# Identifying forward looking sentences in text

Tags: natural-language

I am looking to identify sentences in a text, that talk about future.
It could be future tense, sentences starting with "I expect ... grows" and such.

Can anyone recommend any ready to use solutions for that (preferably, in python)?

Comment: Please define "forward-looking sentences".

Comment: Thanks, updated

Comment: I doubt that this exists. You’ll likely have to define and fit a model for this yourself.